# UILabel not drawing multiline

Tags: ios

I want the label below (in yellow) to be at least two lines rather one.

[image: problem]

I've made sure to uncheck `Use Autolayout` in Interface Builder. When I set the `numberOfLines` from 0 to 2, I get two words stacked on top of each other, with the yellow background tightly fitting the words. The result is the same regardless of whether the `lineBreakMode` is `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` or `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`. It's also the same if I set the frame of the terms Label using the result of `sizeWithAttributes` or not, and it's the same if I use `sizeToFit` or not. I've also tried making the label a `UILabel` rather than a subclass of `UILabel`, which is `TTTAttributedLabel`, but the result is the same.

```
_termsLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
_termsLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
_termsLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
_termsLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
_termsLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
_termsLabel.delegate = self;
_termsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

// Terms label
NSString *termsText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", NSLocalizedString(@"TermsIAgree", nil),
                                                                 NSLocalizedString(@"SettingsTOS", nil),
                                                                 NSLocalizedString(@"LocalizedAnd", nil),
                                                                 NSLocalizedString(@"SettingsPrivacyPolicy", nil)];

_termsLabel.text = termsText;
_termsLabel.linkAttributes = @{ (__bridge NSString *)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName : [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]};
CGSize termsSize = [_termsLabel.text sizeWithAttributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName : _termsLabel.font}];
_termsLabel.frame = CGRectMake(65,
                               395,
                               termsSize.width, termsSize.height);

[_termsLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TOS_URL] withRange:[termsText rangeOfString:NSLocalizedString(@"SettingsTOS", nil)]];
[_termsLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:PRIVACY_POLICY_URL] withRange:[termsText rangeOfString:NSLocalizedString(@"SettingsPrivacyPolicy", nil)]];
```

**EDIT**: By finding the terms text size using `CGSize termsSize = [_termsLabel.text sizeWithFont:_termsLabel.font forWidth:200 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];`
 Yet the `height` of the `termsSize` is then `14`, resulting in just one line:

[image]

How can I get the second line? **SOLUTION** At this point, just add `[_termsLabel sizeToFit]`.

Comment: Does the size of `termsSize` match the size of the label?  Or is the frame changing at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got static text, just set the break mode to wrap, set lines to the number you want, and adjust the label's frame in interface builder until it wraps the way you like. Of you've got dynamic text, you can use `sizeToFit` after setting the label's text to have it automatically adjust it's height to fit the specified width:

1. Set frame to max desired width
2. Set lines to 0
3. Set break mode to wrap
4. Call `sizeToFit`

Answer (score 1):

Determine the maximum width of your label and try [`sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aforWidth%3alineBreakMode%3a) method with this value and desired `NSLineBreakMode` to get the size of resulting string's bounding box.